# How to add a component to the PCL in xamarin cross platform developement?

Tags: xamarin

I have been developing a cross platform Component in Xamarin using PCL. In that I have to add the RESTSharp component to do network operations. But I am unable to add component in the PCL. Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.There are portable class libraries available in the NuGet package manager that can work with other platforms(android,ios) like Microsoft HTTP client.We can also define interfaces in the core library and can do the specific platform implementations in your project by using either dependency injections or IOC containers.can use MVVM light,Autofac libraries.